# some error with mousepressevent()

Tags: qt

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include "my_qlabel.h"
#include<QTimer>
int px;
int py;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
tmrTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect(tmrTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(showthepositionofmouse()));
tmrTimer->start(20);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::showthepositionofmouse()
{
ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString(" x ,  y = ")+QString::number(px)+QString::number(py));
}
void my_qlabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{ 
if (event->button()==Qt::RightButton){
    px = event->x();
    py = event->y();
}
}
```

i Want to display the position of Mouse clicked 
i use `ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString(" x ,  y = ")+QString::number(px)+QString::number(py));` to display this position. although i click mouse,it only show `x,y = 0 0`. why that?

Comment: What does `qDebug() << event->x() << event->y();` shows, when inserted right after your line `py = event->y();` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `py` and `px` that are accessed in `my_qlabel::mousePressEvent`,  are member variables of `my_qlabel` and are not visible to `MainWindow::showthepositionofmouse`.

If you want them to be visible you should send them using a signal and slot.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Here is a way to implement it:

In my_qlabel.h have something like this:

```
class my_qlabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void right_click_xy(int x, int y);
    // ...constructor and other functions

public slots:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    { 
        int px, py;
        if (event->button()==Qt::RightButton){
            px = event->x();
            py = event->y();
            emit right_click_xy(px, py);
        }
    }
}
```

In mainwindow.h have something like this:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // ... constructor and other functions
public slots:
    void on_display_click_xy(int px, int py)
    {
        qDebug() << "Received xy over signal slot:" << px << py;
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString(" x ,  y = ")+QString::number(px)+QString::number(py));
    }
}
```

And inside your MainWindow constructor put the following:

```
QObject::connect(ui->my_qlabel_instance, SIGNAL(right_click_xy(int,int)), 
    this, SLOT(on_display_click_xy(int, int)));
```

Another alternate way of doing this, but is isn't as kosher, would be to drill down into your `ui` object and access `px` and `py` that way.

```
qDebug() << ui->my_qlabel_instance->py;
```

But this is not as elegant, and isn't signaled the same way.

Another idea to look into is to use a `QPoint` object instead of two `int`s.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea is bad, you must process this event within my_qlabel class via signals and slots, not outside of it. I would suggest something like this (emit signal with coordinates of mouse click):

Header my_qlabel.h:

```
#ifndef MY_QLABEL_H
#define MY_QLABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QEvent>

class my_qlabel : public QLabel
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    my_qlabel( const QString & text="", QWidget * parent = 0 );

signals:
    void clicked(QPoint pos);
protected:
    void mouseReleaseEvent ( QMouseEvent * event );
};

#endif // MY_QLABEL
```

Source my_qlabel.cpp:

```
#include "my_qlabel.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>
my_qlabel::my_qlabel( const QString & text, QWidget * parent )
:QLabel(parent)
{
    setText(text);
}
void my_qlabel::mouseReleaseEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
{
    emit clicked(event->pos());
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include "my_qlabel.h"
#include <QtGui/QWidget>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void showthepositionofmouse(QPoint pos);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent)
{
    my_qlabel* label=new my_qlabel("Text of my label",this);
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    QGridLayout *lay=new QGridLayout(this);
    this->setLayout(lay);
    lay->addWidget(label,0,0,1,1);

    connect(label,SIGNAL(clicked(QPoint)),this,SLOT(showthepositionofmouse(QPoint)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::showthepositionofmouse(QPoint pos)
{
    qDebug()<< "Clicked, position="<<pos;
}
```